# AWS Lambda Limits when processing Kinesis Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

Can someone explain what happens to events when a Lambda is subscribed to Kinesis item create events.  There is a limit of 100 concurrent requests for an account in AWS, so if 1,000,000 items are added to kinesis how are the events handled, are they queued up for the next available concurrent lambda?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the FAQ http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

"Q: How does AWS Lambda process data from Amazon Kinesis streams and Amazon DynamoDB Streams?
The Amazon Kinesis and DynamoDB Streams records sent to your AWS Lambda function are strictly serialized, per shard. This means that if you put two records in the same shard, Lambda guarantees that your Lambda function will be successfully invoked with the first record before it is invoked with the second record. If the invocation for one record times out, is throttled, or encounters any other error, Lambda will retry until it succeeds (or the record reaches its 24-hour expiration) before moving on to the next record. The ordering of records across different shards is not guaranteed, and processing of each shard happens in parallel."

What this means is if you have 1M items added to Kinesis, but only one shard, the throttle doesn't matter - you will only have one Lambda function instance reading off that shard in serial, based on the batch size you specified. The more shards you have, the more concurrent invocations your function will see. If you have a stream with > 100 shards, the account limit you mention can be easily increased to whatever you need it to be through AWS customer support. More details here. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

hope that helps!